# Codechef:Piece of Cake(Problem Code: LCH15JAB)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

> You are given a string. Your task is to determine whether number of
> occurrences of some character in the string is equal to the sum of the
> numbers of occurrences of other characters in the string.
>
> Input
>
> The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number
> of test cases. Each of the next T lines contains one string S
> consisting of lowercase latin letters.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, output a single line containing "YES" if the
> string satisfies the condition given above or "NO" otherwise.
>
> Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 4
> acab
> zzqzqq
> abc
> kklkwwww
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> YES
> YES
> NO
> YES
> ```

My code:

```
testcases = int(input())
for i in range(testcases):
    string = list(input())
    x = len(string)
    y = max(string,key=string.count)
    z = string.count(y)
    if z==1:
        print('NO')
    elif x/z==2:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

Codechef gives me Wrong Answer after I've submitted this code. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What does your code output when given the example input?

Comment: The problem seems to be worded ambiguously to me because the occurrence number of other characters may mean all other characters or some characters only. In the latter case "zzqzqqfsf" should return "YES", too (by ignoring "f" and "s").

Comment: My code works fine for all the sample test cases. And the string zzqzqqfsf should return NO as per the given problem constraints. As the string abc is also giving result as a NO.

Comment: I believe all you need to check  is x == 2*z or x//z == 2 and not x/z "/" gives a float.

Comment: I did that but it's still showing Wrong Answer @SomeDude

Comment: Can you please help! @MattDMo

Comment: "ab" would give result "NO" because you check "z == 1" but should be a "YES" instead if the "other characters" are allowed to be a single character.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not giving the right result because of your first `if` statement.

According to your code:

```py
if z==1:
    print('NO')
```

Which means for a test case like `ab` your code will give the output `NO` when it should give the output `yes`. Remove this `if` condition and you will be good to go.

Comment: This example does not correspond with the task description, which apparently asks if the count of a single, distinct character equals the sum of counts of the other distinct characters.

Comment: עד ברקן but the question nowhere mentions the word "distinct".

Comment: "some character" means a single character. A single character means a distinct character. I haven't confirmed it, but it looks like the correct answer was provided in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890289/codechefpiece-of-cakeproblem-code-lch15jab#comment112982667_63890289)

Comment: גלעד ברקן sorry, you were right, I corrected my answer and saw the comment answer just now.